# Vbscript msgbox out of file list

Tags: vbscript, msgbox, filelist

I’m new to vbs, but I need to make a script that copies files from one folder to another, then reads a hole list of copied files and make a log file with those names. This is where I got it covered. Next thing I need to do is to make some sort of msgbox/IEmsg out of this list. This `msgbox` should have all of the file names, line under the line, that script just copied.

This is my script:

```
StrMonth = Month(Date)
 If Len(strMonth) = 1 Then
 strMonth = "0" & strMonth
 End If
 StrDay = Day(Date)
 If Len(strDay) = 1 Then
 strDay = "0" & strDay
 End If
 StrYear = Year(Date)

 FolderName = "c:\Rafel" & strDay & "." & strMonth & "." & StrYear
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(FolderName)
 objFSO.CopyFile "c:\Rafel\files\*.*", FolderName & "\"

  Wscript.Sleep 1000
  IF objFSO.FileExists( FolderName & "\database.txt") THEN
    Wscript.Echo "Folder created, files are copied."
  END IF


SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
FILEFOLDER = FolderName
SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FILEFOLDER)
SET filelist = objFolder.Files
FILELOG = FolderName & "\file log.log"

FOR EACH objFile IN filelist
        FILENAME = FILENAME & "###" & Now & " File copied" & "###" & vbCrlf &_
                  "    File name:" & objFile.Name & vbCrlf &_
                    "    Create date:" & objFile.DateLastModified & vbCrlf &_
                      "    Size:" & objFile.Size & vbCrlf &_
                        vbCrlf
NEXT
SET objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(FILELOG)
              objFile.Write vbCrlf
              objFile.Write(FILENAME) 
              objFile.Close
```

As you can see, it works as far as making copies and creating log file with a list of files. But how can I make a one message box with a list of those files? I’ve tried, `for each` but it just “spam” msgbox for each file.

I'm a noob so pls take that in mind. :)

Comment: Just display FILENAME  in msgbox... Use vbnewline for formatting

Comment: depending on the number of files, `MsgBox` may truncate your message. what if you wrote the results to an html file, then open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom wscript.shell popup box to expand your maximum amount of characters of the msgbox and display the msgbox accordingly.

[More info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/02/how-can-i-display-more-than-1-023-characters-in-a-custom-message-box.aspx)

Code.

```
StrMonth = Month(Date)
 If Len(strMonth) = 1 Then
 strMonth = "0" & strMonth
 End If
 StrDay = Day(Date)
 If Len(strDay) = 1 Then
 strDay = "0" & strDay
 End If
 StrYear = Year(Date)

 FolderName = "c:\Rafel" & strDay & "." & strMonth & "." & StrYear
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(FolderName)
 objFSO.CopyFile "c:\Rafel\files\*.*", FolderName & "\"

  Wscript.Sleep 1000
  IF objFSO.FileExists( FolderName & "\database.txt") THEN
    Wscript.Echo "Folder created, files are copied."
  END IF


SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
FILEFOLDER = FolderName
SET objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FILEFOLDER)
SET filelist = objFolder.Files
FILELOG = FolderName & "\file log.log"

FOR EACH objFile IN filelist
        FILENAME = FILENAME & "###" & Now & " File copied" & "###" & vbCrlf &_
                  "    File name:" & objFile.Name & vbCrlf &_
                    "    Create date:" & objFile.DateLastModified & vbCrlf &_
                      "    Size:" & objFile.Size & vbCrlf &_
                        vbCrlf
NEXT
SET objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(FILELOG)
              objFile.Write vbCrlf
              objFile.Write(FILENAME) 
              objFile.Close

Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Popup FILENAME, 0, "Filenames", 0
```